# Slack always showing the same user when starting up, even if the account is disabled

Tags: slack

It is not really a big thing, but somehow getting on my nerves since long: Whenever I open a certain slack project, I **always** see the direct-messages page of a certain user as first page:

1. I tried to log in and out, with deleting the cookies and other site data.
2. I deleted the direct message history (by clicking the cross next to his name on the sidebar)
3. I even disabled the user account.

No matter what I do - I keep getting the following as the initial screen when go to that slack project:

[image: Screen shot]

What search term should I use? Is that behavior really intended?

Comment: I remember this issue on Github [it could be nice to have a setting for the slack recipe in which the user could select the preferred slack channel to launch on boot. I usually prefer to kick it off on to the "All Unreads" channel, and it seems cumbersome to always have to manually switch it to that channel manually.](https://github.com/meetfranz/recipe-slack/issues/2)

Comment: A bit sad, that I cannot adjust a default channel (or person) - even more weird that Slack seems to choose one for me. Is there any way to find out what's special about my `Volker`?

Comment: There's maybe a support where you can ask this question on https://slack.com/help

Comment: I didn't find any solution or relevant answer yet :)

Comment: I asked the slack support, yet no answer...